# how to use 하네요?

Tags: grammar, translation, word-usage, spoken-korean

**What is the usage of `하네요`?**

**Does the english equivalent of `I'm just saying` similar to `하네요`?**

For example,

```
하네요 여기가 아파.
```

loosely translates to

```
I'm just saying, it hurts here.
```

Another example:

```
정말 날 깜짝 놀라게 하네요.  
I'm just saying, it really boggles my mind.
```

Without the `하네요`, would the sentence `정말 날 깜짝 놀라게` still be grammatically correct?

Also, when translating `정말 날 깜짝 놀라게 하네요.`, could we just ignore the `하네요` and translate it as  `it really boggles my mind.` like [how the translation is shown on Naver](http://endic.naver.com/search.nhn?sLn=kr&searchOption=all&query=%ED%95%98%EB%84%A4%EC%9A%94)?

---

## UPDATED

The context of `하네요 여기가 아파.` comes from a tv drama and the subtitle puts:

```
아이 진짜, 경찰 말도 무시하고
이제 의사말도 무시-그게 아냐.
네요/ 여기가 아파.
```

Comment: No, "하네요 여기가 아파" is ungrammatical and makes no sense.  Where did you get your "translation"?

Comment: It comes from a tv drama and at that point of time, the character was just saying `여기가 아파.` without `하네요`. So when the subtitle has `하네요 여기가 아파.` should the translation be something like `he's saying, "It hurts here".`?

Comment: So, did you actually see "하네요 여기가 아파"?  Because, as I'm saying, that makes no sense.  If you actually saw it, I think "하네요" should attach to the previous sentence: "..... 하네요 / 여기가 아파".  That's the only way I could make sense of it.

Comment: Ah yes, there's a `하네요 / ` what does the `/` mean in that case.

Comment: it means the old sentence ended and a new one started

Comment: ~네요 is used to express that one found out something that one didn't know. Eg: 책은 가방 안에 있네요. (I discovered that the book was inside my bag, when I didn't have any idea where it was previously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- TL;DR: 하네요 does **NOT** mean "I'm just saying"; it is only pure coincidence that "I'm just saying" appeared in your translation at the given position.  하네요 is a particular form of the verb 하다 "do", and just like English "do", 하다 is used in hundreds of different ways, so uses of 하다/하네요/etc. can have wildly different meanings depending on where they appear.  There is no one "matching English phrase".

Your subtitle is showing two (or three?) different people talking at the same time, so the sentences are mixed together.  It should be understood as:

Person A:

> 아이 진짜, 경찰 말도 무시하고 이제 의사말도 무시하네요.
>
> Oh crap, [he is] ignoring what the cop says, and now [he is] also ignoring what the doctor says.

Person B (At the same time):

> 그게 아냐. 여기가 아파.
>
> No, that's not true.  It hurts here.

In Person B's speech, "그게 아냐" means literally "It is not (true)."  The phrase is commonly used to mean "No, you have misunderstood; that's not true; It's not like that."

So, in this particular situation, B is probably trying to say something like "No, that's not true!  It really hurts here.  Believe me!"

So I think the translator inserted **"I'm just saying"** because it fits the situation and adding that makes the English dialogue sound more natural, but it does not correspond to any particular phrase in the Korean dialogue.

Same for "정말 날 깜짝 놀라게 하네요."  It just means "It is really surprising me a lot."  And 하네요 (or, at least some form of the verb 하다) is essential here, because it corresponds to "make" in "make me surprised = 놀라게 하다".  Without it you have an incomplete sentence.  I have no idea why the translator added "I'm just saying", but probably it corresponds to some phrase spoken before or after that Korean sentence.